# Understanding ambiguity in a model: why this is allowed?

Tags: ssas, relationship, sql-server-data-tools

Until know I thought I can't have 2 paths between tables, but currently I have this in my model without any problem:

[image]

I'm creating a model for SSAS 1400 Tabular, if it matters. One more thing: I'm "coming" from PowerBI, where this is not possible to have (I can't set the relationship between `Timesheet` and `Feladat` to "both" (`Timesheet = Munkaidő ráfordítások`)):

[image]

And another one. Here I can't make the relationship between `Megrendelés` and `Dolgozó-Megrendelés Reláció`, because SSDT says:

`Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'There are ambiguous paths between 'Feladat' and 'Dolgozó-Megrendelés Reláció': 'Feladat'->'Megrendelés'->'Dolgozó-Megrendelés Reláció' and 'Feladat'->'Timesheet'->'Dolgozó'->'Dolgozó-Megrendelés Reláció'
'.`

Which I understand, but the first image is contradictory for me then...

[image]

Could someone explain these "phenomenoms" for me?

Answer (score 0):

`Megrendeles Rlacio ======> megrendels` is not a path.
In other words, the direction symbols say you can navigate from `megrendels ===> Dolgozo-Megrendeles Rlacio`, not vice versa.